# Grabbing a number from URL, and using it in node js query

Tags: node.js, parameter-passing

So I'm grabbing a package id number from my URL, and I want to use that to query a db with mongodb.

```
app.get("/order", (req, res) => {

const packageID = req.query.packId;
console.log("Selected package ID is " + packageID);

mongo.connect(mongoUrl, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, client) =>{
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Does Mongo See our selected package ID of " + packageID);
    //select database
    const db = client.db("travelexperts");
    //grab collection
    const collection = db.collection("packages");
    //find variable(s) in packages:
    collection.find({ PackageId: packageID }).toArray((err, result) =>{
        if (err) throw err;
        // res.render("order", {
        //  packages: result
        // });
        console.log(result);
        client.close();
    });

});


res.sendFile(__dirname + "/views/order.html");
```

So the above code works if I manually put an integer value after "PackageId:", but if I try to translate the variable like in the above method my console puts out just "[]" where it should be printing that info. If I use an actual integer it does print the expected array of values. The logs are there for me to make sure the value pulled from the URL is correct (and it is, and these logs appear in my console), but it only actually prints the info from the database if I put replace "packageID" with a number. How can I use this variable as a variable in the "collection.find({ PackageId:}).toArray" line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the values on req.query will be strings. If mongo is expecting a number, you'll need to convert it. Something like this: `const packageID = Number(req.query.packId)`

Comment: ah! Thanks so much. That was it, basically! Storing it as a number that way fixed it.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. If this helped you, please remember to mark it as the answer. Thanks!